# json_decode of a nested arrays returns an empty value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a nested array that I converted to JOSN using json_encode(), and when I tried to convert it back to an array form using json_decode() the returned result was empty.

```
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
```

below is the result of print_r for the json variable:

```
[{
    "result":"SUCCESS",
    "msg":{
        "type":"localScan",
        "res":{
            "status":"0",
            "scan":[
                {
                    "name":"AVG",
                    "result":"0",
                    "type":"Clean"
                },{
                    "name":"ESET NOD32",
                    "result":"2",
                    "type":"Not Working"
                },{
                    "name":"AVAST",
                    "result":0,
                    "type":"Clear"
                },{
                    "name":"Kaspersky",
                    "result":"2",
                    "type":"Not Working"
                },{
                    "name":"Bit-defender",
                    "result":"2",
                    "type":"Not Working"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},{
    "result":"SUCCESS",
    "msg":{
        "type":"localScan",
        "res":{
            "status":"1",
            "scan":[{
                    "name":"AVG",
                    "result":"1",
                    "type":"Autorun"
                },
                {
                    "name":"ESET NOD32",
                    "result":"2",
                    "type":"Not Working"
                },
                {
                    "name":"AVAST",
                    "result":2,
                    "type":"Not Working"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Kaspersky",
                    "result":"2",
                    "type":"Not Working"
                },
                {
                    "name":"Bit-defender",
                    "result":"2",
                    "type":"Not Working"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}]
```

This is a partial array that is used to create the JSON, the json_decode function return value is FALSE.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [result] => SUCCESS 
        [msg] => Array ( 
            [type] => localScan 
            [res] => Array ( 
                [status] => 0 
                [scan] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array ( 
                        [name] => AVG 
                        [result] => 0 
                        [type] => Clean 
                    ) 
                    [1] => Array ( 
                        [name] => ESET NOD32 
                        [result] => 2 
                        [type] => Not Working 
                    ) 
                    [2] => Array ( 
                        [name] => AVAST 
                        [result] => 0 
                        [type] => Clear 
                    ) 
                    [3] => Array 
                    ( 
                        [name] => Kaspersky 
                        [result] => 2 
                        [type] => Not Working 
                    ) 
                    [4] => Array ( 
                        [name] => Bit-defender 
                        [result] => 2 
                        [type] => Not Working 
                    )
                )
            ) 
        ) 
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you provide a PHP array that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Seems valid json. Please provide what you are getting and show your efforts.

Comment: try `var_dump($arr);` to see what you are getting actually.

Comment: have you `die()`'d script after `json_encode` ?

Comment: I have exit(), I'm returning the json from a web service which I built using the tutorial in this link: [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-an-api-centric-web-application--net-23417)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the code that you can try as i have taken the data from your asked question :-

`$jsonString='<String of the Json>';
$data = json_decode($jsonString);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);`

Hop this will help you

Comment: Thank you, this code works... but why? I was using something similar!

Comment: send me the code that you were using so that i can give you appropriate answer on why your code did not run

Comment: I found my problem, I was unintentionally returning other results besides json string and the json_decode() was unable to decode that. It was solved when I removed them. thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't echo the json string -

```
<?php
  $arr = array(); // your array
  echo json_encode( $arr );
?>
```

Comment: I used print_r(), I also used sizeof() to find the result length and it was 0.

Comment: The code itself is very huge and the array is built by getting the results from different parts of it. if there is a problem it might be in the array structure or the encode/decode of the json string.